# Python str/bytes type with cmd

Tags: python, string, cmd, byte

I have written python script to use string in bytes type.

Simple script :

```
s = 'Just string';
b = str.encode(s);
print(type(s));
print(type(b));
```

if I run this script in python IDLE the output is:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'bytes'>
```

And if I run it from cmd; it output another result.

CMD output :

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

I need to use string data in bytes type with cmd.

Why this happened? and how can I correct it?

Comment: You are running IDLE under Python 3, the console under Python 2. The versions differ *materially*.

Comment: Make sure you are running same version of python on both IDEL and cmd.